# magento dashboard not displaying any data

Tags: magento, admin, dashboard

For some reason, LifeTime Sales, Average Orders, Revenue, Tax, Shipping and Quantity as well as the graph are all returning empty data sets. (graph is displaying: "No Data Found" and all the other fields have 0 values). I have tried to edit dashboard/graph.phtml but nothing has changed. I am suspecting there is something wrong with the method getCount(). However, I have no idea where it is defined or how to fix this issue. (i'm on version 1.6.0.0)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only successful orders (with Complete status) are now used to build the data. I believe it was changed in Magento 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Invoiced Orders (with Processing status) are also shown in dashboard, as per Magento 1.7.0.2